# How to combine 2 plots created using different libraries in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created two different plots in shiny application using dygraphs and rCharts libraries respectively.As these are created in two different functions renderChart2 and renderDegraph, I am not able to use par(mfrow=c(2,1)) to combine them.I want to combine these two charts to allocate space efficiently in my application.

server.R code

```
output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({
    data <- data()
 posStart <- as.Date(input$startDate,format="%Y-%m-%d")
     posEnd <-  as.Date(input$endDate,format="%Y-%m-%d")

    if (input$startDate >= input$endDate)
      stop("EndingDate must be > StartingDate")

if (input$startDate < input$endDate){

newdata <- data[paste(posStart,posEnd,sep="::"),]

dygraph(newdata)

    }
  })  

output$chart2 <- renderChart2({
  data <- data()
  posStart <- as.Date(input$startDate,format="%Y-%m-%d")
  posEnd <-  as.Date(input$endDate,format="%Y-%m-%d")
  newdata <- data[paste(posStart,posEnd,sep="::"),]
  #       barChart(newdata)
#   data <- read.csv("C:\\app1\\AAPL.CSV",sep=",")
data.df <- data.frame(cbind(format(index(newdata),"%Y-%m-%d"),coredata(newdata)))
colnames(data.df)[1]<-"date"

data.melt <- melt(data.df)
# newdatamelt <- data.melt[paste(posStart,posEnd,sep="::"),]
print(head(data.df))
print(head(data.melt))
d7 <- dPlot(
  x = "date",
  y = "AAPL.Volume",

  data = data.melt,
  type = "bar"
)

d7$addParams(height = 70,width="100%", dom = 'chart2')

return(d7)
})
```

Thanks